# Is it a bug that pam-auth-update does not enable SSSD even when checked?

Tags: debian, authentication, pam

I am using `sssd` to authenticate and identify users from AD using Kerberos and LDAP, however, I have to add `auth/session/account sufficient pam-sss.so` to `/etc/pam.d/common-*` files even if I check `SSS authentication` in `pam-auth-update`. Is this a bug in the package or am I missing some crucial step?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you are on a Redhat based distro. I usually work with Debian based distros, where pam-auth-update does automatically configure the relevant files, and this e.g. adds a session optional pam_sss.so line. So I would say this sounds a little suspect.

However, sssd originates from the Redhat project, and I would be surprised if they had got it that wrong. Can you post some more details, please, like the distro and version you are using?

Comment: This is debian squeeze.

Comment: Actually, this is a follow-up to your answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/268880/debian-6-0-ad-integration/268958#268958